# gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Linux Subsystem on Windows 10 (Ubuntu)

`youtube-dl: ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)> (caused by URLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))`

`update-ca-certificates
ls /etc/ssl/certs | wc -l
445`

`# openssl s_client -host ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de -port 443`
==> http://paste.itunix.eu/view/raw/f5bf9d07

`# openssl s_client -host ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de -port 443 -debug`
==> http://paste.itunix.eu/view/raw/38b0f2ef

`# openssl s_client -connect ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de:443 -state -nbio`
==> http://paste.itunix.eu/view/raw/0f1fdf4f

On Windows openssl show certificate correctly

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.48]

Comment: I would suggest getting a pcap while performing the `openssl s_client` operation to see if you can capture the protocol and error during the TLS handshake. It sounds like it's failing at the protocol level and not even getting a certificate to present for validation. Also, what version of openssl is used here?

Comment: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(104, 'ECONNRESET')",),)) - skipping

Comment: `# apt update`
`
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.

E: The repository 'https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
`

Comment: I switched Karspersky off and it works.